# How to write pivot query for my data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have following data in my database table

```
PageId  Values
289116  725
310235  453
310235  454
310235  455
281230  453
281230  454
281230  457
307818  453
308962  453
279437  557
```

Based on list of values my application provide, i need to find all pageIDs.
I wrote sample Pivot query

```
select pageid, [556],[1848]  from cmspageAttribute cpa
                            PIVOT
                            (
                                count([Value]) 
                                for Value in ([556],[1848])
                            ) as pvt
                            where Attribute = 'Content Identifier' and  [556]>0 and [1848]>0
```

For example, if application provide 453, 454,455 my result should look like

```
PageId  453 454 455
310235   1   1   1
```

And rest all data should be excluded as i have where clause

But my pivot query giving me 0 records as there is where clause which is checking >0 for each column..

Without Where clause it is giving me data like following

```
pageid  556 1848
302795  0   0
303258  0   0
303258  0   0
303258  0   0
285874  0   0
285874  0   0
285874  0   0
285874  0   0
290131  0   0
290131  0   0
290131  0   0
295127  1   0
303264  0   0
303265  1   0
303265  0   0
303265  0   0
284151  1   0
284346  0   0
281422  1   0
279874  1   0
281422  0   0
306670  0   1
306671  0   1
306672  0   1
306673  0   1
306716  0   1
289116  2   0
```

As you can see, i am getting multiple records for pageId....i want only 1 record per page Id and i believe count(pageid) should be there. If i do count(pageid), i don't get pageid in select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @sql       VARCHAR(8000)='',
        @cols_list VARCHAR(8000)= '453,454,455'

SET @cols_list = '['+Replace(@cols_list, ',', '],[')+']'


SET @sql = 'SELECT PageId,'+@cols_list+'
            FROM   Yourtable
                   PIVOT ( Count ([Values])
                        FOR [Values] IN ('+@cols_list+') ) AS pvt
                          '
PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

**Update :** If you want to filter the records where all the columns count is greater than 0 then

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table2
    ([PageId] int, [Values] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table2
    ([PageId], [Values])
VALUES
    (289116, 725),
    (310235, 453),
    (310235, 454),
    (310235, 455),
    (281230, 453),
    (281230, 454),
    (281230, 457),
    (307818, 453),
    (308962, 453),
    (279437, 557)
;
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @sql          VARCHAR(8000)='',
        @cols_list    VARCHAR(8000)= ' 453, 454,455',
        @where_clause VARCHAR(8000)=''

SET @cols_list = '[' + Replace(@cols_list, ',', '],[') + ']'
SET @where_clause = 'Where ' + Replace(@cols_list, ',', '>0 and ') + '>0'


SET @sql = 'SELECT PageId,' + @cols_list
            + ' FROM  (select PageId,cast([Values] as int) as [Values] from #Table2) a
            PIVOT ( Count ([Values]) FOR [Values] IN (' + @cols_list + ') ) AS pvt
                                ' + @where_clause

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

**Result:**

```
+--------+------+------+-----+
| PageId |  453 |  454 | 455 |
+--------+------+------+-----+
| 310235 |    1 |    1 |   1 |
+--------+------+------+-----+
```